# I think my Http class might be doing work it shouldn't

Tags: php, oop, http, model-view-controller

In my MVC Application there are 5 types of users:

`guest, customer, deliver person, staff and admin`

If a certain user tries to view a page which they do not have access to they get redirected to a certain page and the rest of the script gets terminated.

For example if a customer or delivery person tried a view a page they don't have access to they get redirected back to `http://www.mysite.com/members/` or for example if a guest tries to access the members area they get redirected to the login page.

My `Auth` class does that check and it's also in charge of the login process.

Once `$auth->login($username, $password)` validates the login details it calls

`$this->http->redirect()` at the bottom of the `login()` method.

```
public function redirect() {

    if($this->auth->isLoggedIn()) {

        switch($_SESSION['accountType']) {

            case 1:
            $url = $this->config->setting('url.members');
            break;

            case 2:
            $url = $this->config->setting('url.members');
            break;

            case 3:
            $url = $this->config->setting('url.staff');
            break;

            case 4:
            $url = $this->config->setting('url.admin');
            break;

        }

    }
    else {
        $url = $this->config->setting('url.base') . 'login';
    }

    $this->setHeader('Location', $url);

}
```

The `$http->respond()` method gets called later which sends out any added headers (like the "Location" one added above).

I am thinking that the `redirect()` method is doing work that it should not be doing but I am not sure. To me it seems like my `Http` class should not be checking if people are logged in and what type of accounts people have and it should only be doing stuff like adding headers and sending the response back to the client but then it seems wrong to be to have a `redirect()` method in the `Auth` class too because that should only handle authorization.

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: I tried searching for a question, but couldn't find one.  Could you summarise what your question is please?

Comment: If the class is just supposed to do the job of handling the response from an HTTP protocol point of view, then I would say that yes, it is doing work that it should not be. Rather the `Auth` class should be determining the redirect URL - or at least which setting should be used to obtain it - and you should pass it in as an argument. Also the direct use of `$_SESSION` in the class is bad practice as it introduces global state. You should be converting these values and injecting them rather than accessing `$_SESSION` directly.

Comment: Basically the question is is my Http class doing work it shouldn't? Is it wrong for that class to be checking if a user is logged in etc? It should only deal with modifying http headers and sending http responses shouldn't it? Or is what I'm doing ok?

Comment: @DaveRandom Ok so do you think I my Auth class should determine which URL the redirect is going to and then use $this->http->setHeader('Location', $url') from within the Auth class?

Comment: Yeah just for this example I put in the $_SESSION thing but really I use a $this->user->getAccountType().

Comment: @user1925055 Yes, or at worst you should pass the `'url.members'` etc strings in instead of using the `switch` - but probably the "best" way to do it (in my view) would be to pass in the full URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auth class should not determine the link you will be redirected to, but it should provide the indications needed by the Http class to do the correct redirect. Here's the problem with your approach: Your Http class knows too much. Now, if the url itself is calculated in the Auth class, now the Auth class knows too much. The main ideea would be to use the redirect method with parameters, and the parameters should be decided in the caller class (be it Auth or another one).

Comment: I've changed the `redirect()` method to accept the Location as an argument. The thing is now do you think I should just put `header('Location:' . $url); exit();` in the body of the method or should I used the Http classes `$this->setHeader('Location:' $url); $this->respond(); exit();`. What do you think? They will both do the same obviously but do you think one way would be better than the other? Thanks.

Comment: Since the method is called redirect I suppose it is fine to actually do the redirect inside this method, otherwise you would need to change the method name.